# tilde (~) in java File path

Tags: java, file, testing, path

Any idea why this works fine even on a Windows environment ?
   Can you point me to some docs which explains why this works ?
   I tried to look for it with no results.

```
 package com.my.example;

    import org.junit.Test;

    import java.io.File;
    public class TestPathCreation
    {
        @Test
        public void testPathCreation() throws Exception {
            final String path = "~/.my/dir";
            System.out.println(path);
            File f = new File(path);
            System.out.println(f.mkdirs()); // true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe the path is passed as is to the windows run time and it is responsible to resolve the tilde to user home folder

Comment: In Java 1.8, the file package NIO contains Unix-oriented (Posix) methods and structures. NIO can handle Unix file paths.

Comment: @FlyingDutchman thanks for your answer. problem is I'm using java.io.* and java 7